# Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity And Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I want to authenticate Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity when it has entry in active directory or redirect user to login page to check the database for valid user.

MBM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Integrated Windows Authentication is turned ON in IIS and you've set the identity mode to "windows" in your Web.config, authentication using AD is completely automatic.  You should not need a "login page" per se.  You can and should do checks like this in your global.asax file in the Application_AuthenticateRequest handler.

You really owe it to yourself to read this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649337.aspx

And I can't stress how helpful Keith Brown's book is on getting these concepts understood and working properly:
http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook/HomePage.html